# Trying to merge two lists from a single dataframe together

Tags: python, api, dataframe, get-request

This may be a very noob question, but I'm really struggling to create efficient python code.
Background: I'm trying to get data via an API and extract that data into a CSV. The challenge I'm faced with is the company I'm pulling the API from allows you handle a maximum of 20 products per page (therefore, per request). As you can see from my df2 variable, I can merge all the products into a single variable (albeit an extremely inefficient way). I'm looking for something scalable as I currently have roughly 5,000 products (or 250 pages). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
count = 1
allPages = []
for x in range(2):
    url = "https://COMPANYNAME.repairshopr.com/api/v1/products?page="+str(count)


    headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
    headers["accept"] = "application/json"
    headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer APIVALUE"

    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    allPages.append(json.loads(resp.content.decode('utf-8')))
    count += 1      


# Determine how to get the list into a dataframe

df = DataFrame (allPages)
#Very inefficient way. Need to determine way to loop 
df2 = DataFrame(df.iat[0,0] + df.iat[1,0] + df.iat[2,0] + df.iat[3,0] + df.iat[4,0] + df.iat[5,0] + df.iat[6,0] + df.iat[7,0] + df.iat[8,0] + df.iat[9,0] + df.iat[10,0] + df.iat[11,0] + df.iat[12,0] + df.iat[13,0] + df.iat[14,0] + df.iat[15,0] + df.iat[16,0] + df.iat[17,0] + df.iat[18,0] + df.iat[19,0])

# this is how you write to a CSV file
df2.to_csv(r'C:\Users\lukes\Dropbox\Luke, Dad & Jilly\Grand Tourer\Reports\File Name.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show an example of your input/desired output?

Comment: Hey mate, apricate you reaching out. I've decided to use Microsoft Flow instead of Python for this example, so no need to help. Thank you :)